# Converting a string with decimal pointers and thousand seperators interchangeably to a float in PHP

Tags: php, string, floating-point, type-conversion

I was wondering how to be able to convert any string to a float with the thousand separators and decimal pointers being able to be switched around. This is very useful when dealing with both European and American formats. E.g. `'2,192,520.12'` or `'2.192.520,12'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove all separators but the last by regex

```
[,.](?=.+[,.])
```

so you get `2192520.12` or `2192520,12`. And replace comma to dot. It will be correct number format

```
$re = '/[,.](?=.+[,.])/m';
$subst = '';
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
$result = str_replace(',', '.', $result);  // 2192520.12
```

if you want to deal with numbers as `1,000` than we should set that decimal part can contain max 2 digits. And regex will be

```
[,.](?=.+[,.]|\d{3})
```

Else you can't distinguish 1.027 (one with decimals) and 1027

[**demo**](https://regex101.com/r/IRTCdZ/3)

Comment: That's a very clean solution!

Answer (score 0):

What I came up with:

```
function makeFloat( $numberString ) {
    $commaPos = strrpos( $numberString, ',' );
    $dotPos = strrpos( $numberString, '.' );

    if ( $commaPos === false && $dotPos === false ) {
        // string does not contain comma or a dot
        return (float) $numberString;
    }

    if ( $commaPos === false ) {
        // string does not contain a comma, it does contain a dot
        if ( strpos( $numberString, '.' ) === $dotPos ) { // strpos vs strrpos
            // string contains a single dot, assume the dot is the decimal pointer
            return (float) $numberString;
            // if the string is 1.000 this will cast to 1
            // we do not know if this is a thousand separator
        }
        // string contains multiple dots, assume the dots are thousand separators 
        // (again, string does not contains commas)
        return (float) str_replace( '.', '', $numberString );
    }
    // string contains a comma

    if ( $dotPos === false ) {
        // string does not contain a dot, it does contain a comma
        if ( strpos( $numberString, ',' ) === $commaPos ) { // strpos vs strrpos
            // string contains a single comma, assume the comma is the decimal pointer
            return (float) str_replace( ',', '.', $numberString );
            // if the string is 1,000 this will cast to 1
            // we do not know if this is a thousand separator
        }
        // string contains multiple commas, assume the commas are thousand separators
        return (float) str_replace( ',', '', $numberString );
    }
    // string contains both a comma and a dot

    return $dotPos > $commaPos ?
        // the dot is the decimal pointer
        (float) str_replace( ',', '', $numberString ) :
        // the comma is the decimal pointer
        (float) strtr( $numberString, [ '.' => '', ',' => '.' ] );
}
```

Please feel free to expand upon this method, I'm curious to see what we can come up with.

Comment: Does this have the same problem with *1,000* as it does with *1.000* as it will make it very fragile if you pass a non float into it which only has 1 separator.

Comment: @NigelRen How would you go about solving that?